# Tor on OpenWRT using snowflake bridge for circumventing the internet censorship (Transparent Proxy TP)

Tags: transparent-proxy, firewall

I am using OpenWRT router 22.03.03 in a heavily censored country.
That said all the VPN protocols are filtered and stopped working and the only option for getting connected to the free internet is using Tor and the only bridge that functions properly iwith the Tor is the Snowflake.

I am wondering how can I bring the Snowflake functionality to my OpenWRT router,
the users that are connected to the OpenWRT router should get access to the uncensored internet via Snowflake bridge running with the Tor network.

I have not seen any tutorial on how to use snowflake on OpenWrt router, therefore I am asking for any hint or tutorial to shed a light on this subject.

I am looking for answers to the following questions.

(1) Is the snowflake functionality already built in the Tor package of the OpenWRT or it should be installed as a separate package?

(2) In the case if the snowflake should be installed as a separate package what is/are package(s) that should be installed on the OpenWRT router in order to make the router to access to the Snowflake bridge?

(3) In a case if the Snowflake is already bundled with the Tor package how can I activate it in the tor configuration file?

(4) What is the minimum required settings that I have to configure the OpenWRT router in order to do followings?

(a) Passthorough all the ingoing and outgoing internet traffic of all of the LAN devices thorough the Snowflake bridge, including the DNS request and while the actual configuration should make the router to act like a VPN.

(b) In the case if the Snowflake bridge is not connected to the internet, all the internet traffic be blocked inside the router.

I would appreciate any tutorial or configuration settings for mentioned questions.